# handling hidden field value in controller and model

Tags: php, codeigniter

in my view

```
<select id="gender" name="gender">
                              <option value="">select gender</option>
                               <option value="0">Male </option>
                               <option value="1">Female </option>


                               </select>
```

if gender is female then i want to show another field called "surname". following is the code

```
Surname 

<input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" />
```

And if gender is male then i want show another fields called village,district,etc. I have done hide and show code using js , so my question is how do i handle this field values in controller and model??

Comment: you have to write js code to show / hide fields. Then do same condition check in controller but you have to get value from different field based on selected option

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
switch($_POST['gender']){
case '0':
// do Something for 0
break;
case '1':
// do Something for 1
break;
default:
// Something went wrong or form has been tampered.
}
```